100Mbps-1000Mbps NICs all limited to ~40Mbps?
I have paid for 1000Mbps for quite some time from my ISP and have always had trouble with it maxing out at ~40Mbps. I always faulted my VPN and just suffered through it.
I finally tried to troubleshoot the issue and connected my netbook to the ONT (via ethernet), which has a NIC capable of 100Mbps (per https://askubuntu.com/questions/431911/how-can-i-verify-the-speed-of-my-nic-in-ubuntu/1048051#1048051), but I still only got ~40Mbps.
So I had the ISP send a technician out, and after much push-back because they wanted to connect to my router rather than use their own tools, they finally agreed to hook up one of their routers to test the connection. If I recall, initially they couldn't get any internet through to their router whatsoever, but after a conversation with their IT, finally got it to push 700+Mbps to their personal cell phone.
I have tried to replicate the technician's results with just about every device I have on hand, including a Roku, 3 Kubuntu desktops with NICs capable of 1000Mbps, multiple <4y/o Android smartphones, and the 100Mbps-capable Lubuntu live-USB netbook mentioned previously, testing via Cat5e/Cat6 ethernet connected directly to the ONT and to their router, but also to my router as well as via powerline adapters and WiFi.
The only combination of the above that came remotely close was a Google Pixel 7 connected via WiFi, which achieved ~200Mbps at point-blank range with their router, when it should be pushing 700+ (or now that I asked to downgrade to 500, maybe 400+?)
Every other device? ~40Mbps. Not 5, not 100, but ~40Mbps every time.
How do I find out what the limiting factor is and fix it?
Edits:
Clarification per request by music2myear:
Both my router and their router produce 40Mbps to all but the Pixel 7 and that technician's phone of unknown make/model. My router is a Netgear R6700 v3 running DD-WRT v3.0-r52369 std (04/20/23), theirs is a Sagemcom Fast5290. I've also tried a Netgear R6700 v2 with firmware from 6/2024, a PrivacyHero AX1800, and an Asus RT-AX3000. All had the same result.
Per request by Silbee:
Steam will transfer games from PC to PC within the network at about that same speed, and I found DD-WRT's internal network speed tester, which claims ~34Mbps. Strangely, that same utility, "Speedchecker," says my outbound connections are 6.21Mbps, which I know is false.

What are your network device's, router's, modem's models? It seems pretty clear the issue is your router, if their router got those speeds.

Both my router and their router produce 40Mbps to all but the Pixel 7 and that technician's phone of unknown make/model. My router is a Netgear R6700 v3 running DD-WRT v3.0-r52369 std (04/20/23), theirs is a Sagemcom Fast5290. I've also tried a Netgear R6700 v2 with firmware from 6/2024, a PrivacyHero AX1800, and an Asus RT-AX3000. All had the same result.

Add that info to the question, please. Your question has some information, but more information, like these additional details, need to in it in order to give us a better idea of your situation.

@music2myear Done, thank you.

What about internal network traffic ?

Steam transferring a game from one computer to another on the same network is also restricted to the same ~40Mbps. I'm not entirely sure that's a good metric to measure that, though.

I suggest removing everything from the question that is irrelevant to the problem: Wi-Fi, Powerline, your routers. Also remove all sources of interference, and test with a good quality Ethernet cable connected directly to the ONT. If you get 500 Mbps there, you can include and test the next component, a router.

Still only 40 Mbps even when directly connected to the ONT. The laptop used has a NIC that should support 100.

Please describe, in your question, how exactly you are measuring the bandwidth. // Calling the device a Netbook sort-of implies it has woefully inadequate performance for browser-based tests. Even a CLI-based test could be limited by CPU performance. Also, downloading a file involves saving it somewhere, which could further limit speeds.

I have been using a mix of DD-WRT's on-board speed test, speedtest.net, and testmy.net
